# TabItem gets blocked permanently

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I am experiencing a very weird problem: In WPF I have a tabControl which contains 3 tabItems. I have made a binding from the tabControl's SelectedIndex to a property inside my viewModel class in "OneWayToSource" mode.

Here's the XAML code:

```
<TabControl Name="mainTabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex, Mode=OneWayToSource}"  >
        <TabItem Header="Tab 01" Name="tab01"> ... </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 02" Name="tab02"> ... </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 03" Name="tab03"> ... </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And in my viewModel:

```
    private int m_selectedTabIndex;
    public int SelectedTabIndex
    {
        get
        { return m_selectedTabIndex; }
        set
        {
            SetAndNotify(ref m_selectedTabIndex, value, () => SelectedTabIndex);
            SelectedTabChanged();
        }
    }

private void SelectedTabChanged()
    {
        // Some code
    }
```

As you can see, everytime my viewModel's `SelectedTabIndex` property changes, the `SelectedTabChanged()` method is executed, this works perfectly.

My weird problem is that: **When I show a message using for example `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Some Text")` inside my `SelectedTabChanged()` method, I select another tabItem and the previous selected tab gets blocked, it looks like selected, but it remains selected permanently, I cannot see its content anymore.**

**Just to clarify: As I stated before, this weird issue only happens when a modal window is showed**

Why is happening? How can I solve this issue?

I hope I explained myself clearly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Since I am new in WPF I really dont understand why a modal window make the tabs get blocked. But I was searching and found that the Dispatcher class allows one to execute asynchronously a method which prevent any control from get blocked.

I changed my viewModel code as below:

```
public int SelectedTabIndex
    {
        get
        { return m_selectedTabIndex; }
        set
        {
            SetAndNotify(ref m_selectedTabIndex, value, () => SelectedTabIndex);
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SelectedTabChanged), null);
        }
    }
```

The line that really helped me was the following:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(SelectedTabChanged), null);
```

Hope this help someone else can be experiencing some similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure I understand your problem, but a `MessageBox.Show` will spawn a nested message pump and block the main `Dispatcher`, thus 'freezing' the main window (which is why it is modal).
If you need to show a `MessageBox` style alert without it being modal, then my advice is to create a panel with your message in it that exists in the `TabItem` with a hidden visibility, then make it visible when required to show you message. Your Tab selections should still work in that scenario

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but Actually I need to show a modal window since it could be the message of an exception, so, I am trying to be able to show any modal window without blocking the tab

Comment: If its modal, it will block the tabcontrol, so there is no possible solution IMO